# Configuring Informix database for JDBC Connection

Tags: java, jdbc, informix

I'm writing my first android app via Eclipse.  I am trying to make a connection to my informix database.  I have installed informix's client-side drivers on my system and the program picks them up when I run the Class.forName() method.  However, my connection URL fails everytime.  I have looked at many examples online as well as read much of IBM's documentation on this.  I'm convinced there is some type of driver I need to install on my server??

Any insight would be great, thanks!

Comment: Post the relevant code and any exceptions. It makes it much easier to offer advice and solutions.

Comment: I think I solved my own problem.  My informix version is 7.25, and according to IBM's documents, I need a newer version.